# Asus K53E wont hibernate/suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate, suspend-resume

I just recently installed ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. everything works great however when I get it to hibernate my screen turns black but still backlit and my cpu is still running. How can I fix this?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How large is your swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (hibernate/suspend) and this solution works for my Asus K53E (I use step 2, not older step 2):

http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug/comment-page-10#header-0

Good luck!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick nicely. Thank you very much for finding that!

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

See the answer from @PierreLachance - fixed this problem

=================================================

Have (possibly) the same problem, same laptop model. Hibernate saves to disk, but does not power off. Not essential, but annoying.

Up-to-date Ubuntu 11.10

uname -a:

```
Linux sphinx 3.0.0-16-generic-pae #29-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 14 13:56:31 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Hardware:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 100
03:00.0 USB Controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

The appropriate dmesg section:

```
[26766.181283] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[26767.748879] PM: Marking nosave pages: 000000000009e000 - 0000000000100000
[26767.748884] PM: Marking nosave pages: 0000000020000000 - 0000000020200000
[26767.748893] PM: Basic memory bitmaps created
[26767.748895] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[26767.830587] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[26767.846787] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[26767.863074] PM: Preallocating image memory... done (allocated 447521 pages)
[26768.104837] PM: Allocated 1790084 kbytes in 0.24 seconds (7458.68 MB/s)
[26768.104840] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[26768.104992] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[26768.314611] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A disabled
[26768.330225] PM: freeze of drv:HDA Intel dev:0000:00:1b.0 complete after 224.511 msecs
[26768.330348] PM: freeze of drv: dev:pci0000:00 complete after 224.602 msecs
[26768.330354] PM: freeze of devices complete after 225.759 msecs
[26768.330842] PM: late freeze of devices complete after 0.485 msecs
[26768.331004] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[26768.358785] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[26768.359471] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[26768.462072] CPU 1 is now offline
[26768.462411] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[26768.462493] PM: Creating hibernation image:
[26768.579475] PM: Need to copy 446872 pages
[26768.579478] PM: Normal pages needed: 79729 + 1024, available pages: 147880
[26768.462518] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[26768.462926] Extended CMOS year: 2000
[26768.462951] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[26768.463042] Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[26768.463044] smpboot cpu 1: start_ip = 9a000
[26768.473225] Initializing CPU#1
[26768.571086] CPU1 is up
[26768.572285] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[26768.574459] Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #1
```

It doesn't seem to be logging any problems between writing the system state to disk and waking up. A normal shutdown works fine.

Comment: Try https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/903825